# Not able to execute npm install on my Gulp+Angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, gulp

I have created a project wherein i have used gulp with Angular2. But getting following error trace while executing npm install:

```
> typings install && gulp check.versions && npm prune


`-- xhr2

[12:06:55] Requiring external module ts-node/register
----------------------------------
? Unable to compile TypeScript

gulpfile.ts (1,23): Cannot find module 'gulp'. (2307)
tools\config.ts (1,28): Cannot find module 'fs'. (2307)
tools\config.ts (2,20): Cannot find module 'yargs'. (2307)
tools\config.ts (3,31): Cannot find module 'path'. (2307)
tools\config.ts (4,24): Cannot find module 'chalk'. (2307)
tools\config.ts (15,52): Cannot find name '__dirname'. (2304)
tools\config.ts (64,3): Cannot find name 'process'. (2304)
tools\config.ts (221,50): Cannot find name 'require'. (2304)
tools\configW.ts (1,28): Cannot find module 'fs'. (2307)
tools\configW.ts (2,20): Cannot find module 'yargs'. (2307)
tools\configW.ts (3,31): Cannot find module 'path'. (2307)
tools\configW.ts (4,24): Cannot find module 'chalk'. (2307)
tools\configW.ts (5,23): Cannot find module 'gulp-util'. (2307)
tools\configW.ts (17,52): Cannot find name '__dirname'. (2304)
tools\configW.ts (36,52): Cannot find name '__dirname'. (2304)
tools\configW.ts (72,3): Cannot find name 'process'. (2304)
tools\configW.ts (236,50): Cannot find name 'require'. (2304)
tools\manual_typings\merge-stream.d.ts (2,36): Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'. (2503)
tools\manual_typings\merge-stream.d.ts (3,33): Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'. (2503)
tools\manual_typings\merge-stream.d.ts (4,17): Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'. (2503)
tools\manual_typings\systemjs-builder.d.ts (4,60): Cannot find name 'Promise'. (2304)
tools\manual_typings\systemjs-builder.d.ts (5,65): Cannot find name 'Promise'. (2304)
tools\utils.ts (9,17): Cannot find name 'require'. (2304)
tools\utils\code_change_tools.ts (2,30): Cannot find module 'browser-sync'. (2307)
tools\utils\code_change_tools.ts (10,18): Cannot find name 'require'. (2304)
tools\utils\server.ts (1,26): Cannot find module 'express'. (2307)
tools\utils\server.ts (3,30): Cannot find module 'serve-static'. (2307)
tools\utils\server.ts (5,23): Cannot find module 'path'. (2307)
tools\utils\server.ts (22,25): Cannot find name 'process'. (2304)
tools\utils\server.ts (35,25): Cannot find name 'process'. (2304)
tools\utils\tasks_tools.ts (1,23): Cannot find module 'gulp'. (2307)
tools\utils\tasks_tools.ts (2,23): Cannot find module 'gulp-util'. (2307)
tools\utils\tasks_tools.ts (3,24): Cannot find module 'chalk'. (2307)
tools\utils\tasks_tools.ts (4,34): Cannot find module 'gulp-load-plugins'. (2307)
tools\utils\tasks_tools.ts (5,31): Cannot find module 'run-sequence'. (2307)
tools\utils\tasks_tools.ts (6,50): Cannot find module 'fs'. (2307)
tools\utils\tasks_tools.ts (7,20): Cannot find module 'path'. (2307)
tools\utils\tasks_tools.ts (19,10): Cannot find name 'require'. (2304)
tools\utils\template_injectables.ts (4,20): Cannot find module 'path'. (2307)
----------------------------------
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\...\tool-design\frontend\node_modules\es5-ext\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\...\tool-design\frontend\node_modules\escodegen\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\..\tool-design\frontend\node_modules\exit\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\..\tool-design\frontend\node_modules\escodegen\node_modules\source-map\package.json'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! wi-automation-frontend@0.0.1 postinstall: `typings install && gulp check.versions && npm prune`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

The gulp file that i have is:

```
import * as gulp from 'gulp';
import {runSequence, task} from './tools/utils';

// --------------
// Clean (override).
gulp.task('clean', done => task('clean', 'all')(done));
gulp.task('clean.dev', done => task('clean', 'dev')(done));
gulp.task('clean.prod', done => task('clean', 'prod')(done));
gulp.task('clean.prodW', done => task('clean', 'prodW')(done));
gulp.task('check.versions', () => task('check.versions'));
gulp.task('build.docs', () => task('build.docs'));
gulp.task('serve.docs', () => task('serve.docs'));
gulp.task('serve.coverage', task('serve.coverage'));

// --------------
// Build dev.
gulp.task('build.dev', done =>
  runSequence('clean.dev',
    'tslint',
    'build.assets.dev',
    'build.js.dev',
    'build.index.dev',
    done));

// --------------
// Build dev watch.
gulp.task('build.dev.watch', done =>
  runSequence('build.dev',
    'watch.dev',
    done));

// --------------
// Build e2e.
gulp.task('build.e2e', done =>
  runSequence('clean.dev',
    'tslint',
    'build.assets.dev',
    'build.js.e2e',
    'build.index.dev',
    done));

// --------------
// Build prod.
gulp.task('build.prod', done =>
  runSequence('clean.prod',
    // 'tslint',
    'build.assets.prod',
    'build.html_css.prod',
    'build.js.prod',
    'build.bundles',
    'build.bundles.app',
    'build.index.prod',
    done));

// Move.
gulp.task('build.prod.move', done =>
  runSequence('build.prod',
    'build.move.prod',
    done));
// --------------
// Build test.
gulp.task('build.test', done =>
  runSequence('clean.dev',
    'tslint',
    'build.assets.dev',
    'build.js.test',
    'build.index.dev',
    done));

// --------------
// Build test watch.
gulp.task('build.test.watch', done =>
  runSequence('build.test',
    'watch.test',
    done));

// --------------
// Docs
// Disabled until https://github.com/sebastian-lenz/typedoc/issues/162 gets resolved
gulp.task('docs', done =>
  runSequence('build.docs',
    'serve.docs',
    done));

// --------------
// Serve dev
gulp.task('serve.dev', done =>
  runSequence('build.dev',
    'server.start',
    'watch.serve',
    done));

// --------------
// Serve e2e
gulp.task('serve.e2e', done =>
  runSequence('build.e2e',
    'server.start',
    'watch.serve',
    done));

// --------------
// Serve prod
gulp.task('serve.prod', done =>
  runSequence('build.prod',
    'server.start',
    'watch.serve',
    done));

// --------------
// Test.
gulp.task('test', done =>
  runSequence('build.test',
    'karma.start',
    done));

// Build prod.
gulp.task('build.prodW', done =>
  runSequence('clean.prodW',
    'tslint',
    'build.assets.prodW',
    'build.html_css.prodW',
    'build.js.prodW',
    'build.bundlesW',
    'build.bundles.appW',
    // 'build.index.prodW',
    'build.index.inject.asset.prodW',
    done));

// Move.
gulp.task('build.moveW.prodW', done =>
  runSequence('build.prodW',
    'build.move.prodW',
    done));


// Serve prod
gulp.task('serve.prodW', done =>
  runSequence('build.moveW.prodW',
    'server.start',
    'watch.serve',
    done));
```

Please help me to correct this issue. I have tried removing gulp globally and reinstalled gulp, typings and ts-node already.

Comment: clear the npm cache and execute again.

Comment: i tried multiple times but experienced the same issue.

Comment: update your package.json

Comment: which part i need to update or how i need to update it?

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of thoughts:

1. Are you doing your npm install from your project root directory? If not go to project root and install from there.
2. Are your modules globally or locally installed? (connected to #1)
3. Did you check your `package.json`? Are the entries matched up to what you know should be installed?
4. Do you have read/write permissions on the directories? (Kind of critical).